# Saving bitmap at custom path and with custom name

Tags: android, bitmap, save, image-capture

my program captures an image (as bitmap) but I don't know (and couldn't find) how to save it with a custom name at a custom path... Here's my image capture codes. Can I do it? Or is there any way saving it as another data type, not bitmap? some help will be great. Thanks.

```
public class ShowMessagesPage extends Activity {
final static int CAMERA_RESULT = 0;
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_messages_page);

    Button userButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    userButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        error();
        }});

    Button buttonPhoto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPhoto);
    buttonPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_RESULT);
        }});}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
          Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
          Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");



        }
      }

and the other codes..........
```

Comment: [http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html](go)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent getCameraImage = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

File cameraFolder;

if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    cameraFolder = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"folder_name_of_your_choice");
else
    cameraFolder= ShowMessagesPage.this.getCacheDir();
if(!cameraFolder.exists())
    cameraFolder.mkdirs();

File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "folder_name_of_your_choice/camera_snap.jpg");
getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
initialURI = Uri.fromFile(photo);

startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, CAMERA_RESULT);
```

And in the onActivityResult(), process the `Uri initialURI` to get your Image which is already saved to the path you have chosen in the code posted above. The name of the image file will be: **camera_snap.jpg**

*Note: The `Uri initialURI` is declared globally.*

Comment: Sorry but Eclipse says there is no methods or variables like "StatusUpdate" and "reqcdCameraImage"... Also there is no imports for them :/

Comment: @ArdaOğulÜçpınar: My bad, I pasted my code as is and forgot these modifications. Check the edit.

Comment: OMG :D  I should have seen it :D thanx :D

Comment: @ArdaOğulÜçpınar: Happens to the best of us. :-)

Comment: I have a problem with that... When I take the picture and press "ok", program doesn't go back to the previous activity. Just stuck at the camera activity. :/